# What is the maximum order of the elements in the group of order ${p^4}$ with 3-generator?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let say we have a group of order ${p^4}$ with 3-generator $\langle x \rangle$, $\langle y \rangle$ and $\langle z \rangle$ where $|\langle x \rangle|={p^2}$, $|\langle y \rangle|=p$ and $|\langle z \rangle|=p$.

Since the order of elements divides the order of groups, thus, the order of elements is either 1, $p$, ${p^2}$ ${p^3}$ or ${p^4}$.

Note that the order of the elements from $\langle x \rangle$ is 1, $p$ or ${p^2}$. Meanwhile, the order of the elements from $\langle y \rangle$ and $\langle z \rangle$ is either 1 or $p$.

There is no elements of order ${p^4}$ because this group is not a cyclic group since cyclic group only have one generator. So, the maximum order of the elements in this group cannot be ${p^4}$.

How about the elements of order ${p^3}$? Is it there is any element of order ${p^3}$? If no, how to show it?

Thank you.

Comment: Take $p=2$. All groups of order 16 are well known. Orders of their elements and generators are also well known. Just check GAP or Magma.

Comment: how about $p>2$ and $p$ is odd prime? yes, i have checked in GAP. the order of the elements is either 1, $p$ or ${p^2}$. i just want to find the way to prove it in general.

Comment: Just because you have a list of 3 generators does not mean the group cannot be generated by fewer elements; so your argument for why it isn’t cyclic is not right. The reason it is not cyclic is that if the group were abelian, the elements would be of order at most $p^2$. Now, if $p\gt 3$, then $G$ is of small class, hence regular, and therefore the order of $ab$ is bounded above by the maximum of the orders of $a$ and $b$, which will prove there are no elements of order $p^3$; the only value of $p$ for which you could have an element of order $p^3$ is $p=3$.

Comment: i need to read and understand first about the 'regular' then maybe i can understand why the order of ab is bounded above by the maximum of the orders of a and b. by the way, do you have any suggestion of article or books which mention about this? So that i can try to study and understand it. thank you for the answer and help .

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking. Are  you assuming that the group cannot be generated by two elements?

Comment: no, i mean what is the maximum order of the elements in this group including the elements generated by generator x and y, x and z, y and z. what is the possibilities of the order of the product of two elements in this group?

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ be the group in question. Assume first that $3$ is the minimal number of generators of G. Then $G/\Phi(G)$ is elementary abelian of order $p^3$ and hence has exponent $p$, and $\Phi(G)$ also has exponent $p$ and hence $G$.

$G$ is clearly not cyclic, so the minimal number of generators must be $2$.

If $p=2$, then we could have $G= D_{16}$ dihedral of order $16$, which has exponent $8=p^3$. So when $p=2$  it is possible to have an element of order $p^3=8$. ($G$ could also be the semidihedral group in that case.)

But when $p$ is odd we cannot have element of order $p^3$. For suppose $x$ is such an element. Then $\langle x \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, and $G = \langle x,y \rangle$ for some $y \in G$.

Now if $G$ was abelian it would have exponent $p^2$ so it must be nonabelian, and hence conjugation by $y$ induces an automorphism of $\langle x \rangle$ of order $p$.

Let $A = {\rm Aut}(\langle x \rangle)$. Then $|A| = p^2(p-1)$, and $A$ has a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup generated by $x \mapsto x^{1+p}$. So we can assume that the element of $A$ induced by conjugation by $y$ is $x \mapsto x^{1+p^2}$; in other words, $y^{-1}xy=x^{1+p^2}$.

So $[G,G] = \langle x^{p^2} \rangle$ has order $p$, and we must have $G/[G,G] \cong C_{p^2} \times C_{p}$. Now any generting set of $G/[G,G]$ must include an element of order $p^2$, and all such elements $g[G,G]$ satisfy $g^p[G,G] = x^p[G,G]$ and hence $g^{p^2} = x^{p^2} \ne 1$. So all generating sets of $G$ contain an element of order $p^3$.